# How to Get aggregated reports at web application level in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

As we have different reports at site and site collection level like `audit` and `search` related.

How I can get reports at web application level?

What if I need number of hits at site collection level and report would be aggregated at web application level.